# На Spring пишу мэсседжер, при попытке создать ассоциацию друзей через @OneToMany в зависимости от fetchType выдает разные ошибки

Tags: java, spring

Весь код сущности

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

public User() {

}

public User(String nick, String pass, String name, String surname, String email, boolean isActivated) {
    this.username = nick;
    this.password = pass;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.email = email;
    this.isActivated = isActivated;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String username, password, name, surname, email;

boolean isActivated;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Dialogue.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Dialogue> dialogues = new ArrayList<>();

public Collection<Dialogue> getDialogues() {
    return dialogues;
}

public void setDialogues(Collection<Dialogue> dialogues) {
    this.dialogues = dialogues;
}



public Collection<User> getFriends() {
    return friends;
}


public void setFriends(Collection<User> friends) {
    this.friends = friends;
}

@OneToMany(targetEntity = User.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<User> friends = new ArrayList<>();


@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<Role> roles;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public boolean isActivated() {
    return isActivated;
}

public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
    isActivated = activated;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return isActivated();
}
```

"Больная часть"

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = User.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<User> friends = new ArrayList<>();

public Collection<User> getFriends() {
    return friends;
}


public void setFriends(Collection<User> friends) {
    this.friends = friends;
}
```

При fetchType Eager выдаёт ошибку

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialogueRepository' defined in Kejkers.Rgr.repo.DialogueRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [Kejkers.Rgr.Models.User.dialogues, Kejkers.Rgr.Models.User.friends]
```

при fetchType LAZY сервер запускается, однако при посещении страницы

```
@GetMapping("/friends")
public String friends (@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, Model model)
{
    Iterable<User> friends = user.getFriends();
    model.addAttribute("friends",friends);
return "friends";
}
```

Всё ломается

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/friends.html]")
```

при поиске проблемы с помощью точки останов выдает такую строчку

```
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.
```

@Transactional пробовал, костыли пробовал.

Comment: вообще хибернейт очень не любит интерфейс лист. лучше используйте сет вместо этого private Collection<User> friends = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 0):

### MultipleBagFetchException

Согласно ответу одного из создателей Hibernate, Vlad Mihalcea (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055523/9978153):

Когда вы ставите `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` над несколькими `@OneToMany` полями, вы получаете ошибку `MultipleBagFetchException` при попытке запросить такую сущность. Это защита от потенциально огромного количества записей, которые придется обработать в рамках запроса из-за двойгого JOIN.

Вам необходимо вернуть `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`

### LazyInitializationException

`LazyInitializationException` случается, когда вы пытаетесь получить лениво связанные сущности (`@OneToMany` + `FetchType.LAZY`), вне сессии. Самый простой способ открыть сессию - использовать @Transactional.

Ваш вопрос содержит упоминание "@Transactional  пробовал, костыли пробовал". Было бы замечательно, если бы вы рассказали, где именно вы пробовали установить @Transactional и какие "костыли" вы пробовали.

### Решение 1. Возвращать инициализированных пользователей

Судя по всему, Вы используете Spring Security.
Вам необходимо возвращать полностью инициализированных пользователей из `UserDetailsService`
Для этого можно просто обратиться к списку друзей в рамках сессии, которая возвращаем Вам пользователя.
Но это решение заставит делать запрос за `friends` всегда, даже когда это на самом деле не нужно.

### Решение 2. Использовать отдельный метод репозитория для получения списка друзей.

Это решение является более простым и не требует глубокого погружения.
Можно создать метод в репозитории, который будет возвращать список друзей для пользователя, и не зависеть от возможностей `@ObeToMany`.

В таком случае можно применить запрос.

```
SELECT u from User u WHERE :user in u.friends
```

P.S. Пока я пытался придумать запрос на HQL, я заметил, что `User` имеет рекурсивную `@OneToMany` связь (`User` имeет ссылку на `User` в поле `friends`). Не стоит ли заменить связь на `@ManyToMany`?